# How can I save the high score for a 2D game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I have a script that doesn't save the high score automatically and before I put the restart button my high score was saved without any code. I want the high score to be saved even if the player restarts the game .This is my code for the SCORE:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int score;
    public Text ScoreText;
    public int highscore;
    public Text highScoreText;


    void Start()
    {
        highscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore: " + highscore);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        ScoreText.text = "Score: " + score;
        highScoreText.text = highscore.ToString();
        if (score > highscore)
        {
            highscore = score;

            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore: ", highscore);
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Debug.Log("collider is working");
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Score: ")
        {
            score++;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code for the restart button:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;

public class RestartGame : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void RestartsGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name); // loads current scene
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use PlayerPrefs.setInt inside the UPDATE function.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't be using player prefs to save game data (such as highscore), but your own file. PlayerPrefs is meant for things like the player's volume level, mute status, or preferred control scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problems with the keys used by `PlayerPrefs`:

```
void Start()
{
    highscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore");
}

void Update()
{
    ScoreText.text = "Score: " + score;
    highScoreText.text = highscore.ToString();
    if (score > highscore)
    {
        highscore = score;

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", highscore);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Draco18s

> you shouldn't be using player prefs to save game data (such as
>   highscore).

Here is how you can save it in a json file if you want. It also adds more flexibility in case you want to add things like a top 10 score or something like that.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class HighestScoreJson
{
    /// <summary>
    /// //Returns the path to the highestScoreFile
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetPathToHighestScore() {
        return Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "HighestScore.json"); //You can look for info about the unity streamingAssets folder in the unity documentation
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the highestScore
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static HighestScore GetHighestScore() {
        string path = GetPathToHighestScore();

        if (!File.Exists(path)) //Checks if the file exists
        {
            HighestScore highestScore = new HighestScore();
            string jsonObj = JsonUtility.ToJson(highestScore);
            //Debug.Log("SavedJsonFile: " + jsonObj);
            FileInfo defaultFile = new FileInfo(path);
            defaultFile.Directory.Create(); // If the directory already exists, this method does nothing.
            File.WriteAllText(path, jsonObj);
        }

        string file = File.ReadAllText(path);
        HighestScore highestScoreJson = JsonUtility.FromJson<HighestScore>(file);
        //Debug.Log(highestScoreJson.highestScore); //here you can check the value on the debug if you want
        return highestScoreJson;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Save a new highestScore
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="highestScore"></param>
    public static void SaveHighestScore(int highestScoreValue) {
    string path = GetPathToHighestScore();
    HighestScore highestScore = new HighestScore();
    highestScore.highestScore = highestScoreValue;
    string jsonObj = JsonUtility.ToJson(highestScore);
    //Debug.Log("SavedJsonFile: " + jsonObj);
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
    file.Directory.Create(); // If the directory already exists, this method does nothing.
    File.WriteAllText(path, jsonObj);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// This class holds the highestScore
/// </summary>
public class HighestScore
{
    public int highestScore;
    //You can also create a list if you want with the top 10 or something like that
}
```

Then you would use it like this

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int score;
    public Text ScoreText;
    public int highscore;
    public Text highScoreText;


    void Start()
    {               
        highscore = HighestScoreJson.GetHighestScore().highestScore; 
    }

    void Update()
    {
        ScoreText.text = "Score: " + score;
        highScoreText.text = highscore.ToString();
        if (score > highscore)
        {
            highscore = score;
        HighestScoreJson.SaveHighestScore(highscore);
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Debug.Log("collider is working");
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Score: ")
        {
            score++;
        }
    }

}
```

You can probably optimize you calls if you take out the update and only call change your texts when the score changes.

```
void Update() //Don't need it
{
}
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Debug.Log("collider is working");
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Score: ")
    {
        score++;
        ScoreText.text = "Score: " + score;
        highScoreText.text = highscore.ToString();
        if (score > highscore)
        {
           highscore = score;
           HighestScoreJson.SaveHighestScore(highscore);
        }
    }
}
```